# An issue with type matching (hopefully possible to fix) F#

Tags: f#

So i have type Gitem

```
type Gitem = 
    |Weapon of Weapon
    |Bomb of Bomb
    |Monster of Monster
    |Armour of Armour
    |Potion of Potion
    |None
```

This is used to store different types of objects within a record, to be clear, the types I'm having issues with look like so:

```
type Monster={
    name:string;
    dVal:float;
    dType:DamType;
    hVal:float;
    info:string;
    dInfo:string;
    dCry:string;
    Special:bool;
    sItem:obj;
 }        



type Armour={
    name:string;
    aVal:float;
    dType:DamType;
    info:string;
    iSpace:int;
    hidden:bool;
}

type Weapon={
    name:string;
    dVal:float;
    dType:DamType;
    info:string;
    iSpace:int;
    hidden:bool;
}
```

The problem is, Gitem includes Monster as a potential type, however monsters can have a bomb, weapon or armour as their sItem, i made the type object due to this.
Later in my code i write :

```
match monster.sItem with  //gives them the item if the monster drops one
                    | Bomb bomb ->
                        procBomb bomb 

                    | Weapon weap -> 
                        procWeap weap

                    | Potion pot ->
                        procPot pot

                    | Armour arm ->
                        procArm arm
```

I get the error that the expression should be Gitem, not obj, however I cannot make the monster sitem field as Gitem, it is not allowed due to Gitem using monster as a possible type. I tried making another type like Gitem that has all types apart from monster, however this causes problems too.
I'm second year of university, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutual recursive types can be declared using the `and` keyword:

```
type A = { b : B }
and B = { a : A option }
```

Also, F# 4.1 introduced [recursive modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules#module-rec-allowing-mutual-recursive-code-at-the-module-level) (and namespaces), which allow mutual recursive types at a module (namespace) level. This is useful if you have many lengthy mutually dependent types (note that there’s no`and`):

```
module rec RecursiveModule =
    type A = { b : B }
    type B = { a : A option }
```

Comment: I’m trying to understand that, so I would declare type Monster  then after the and keyword, define type Gitem?This would allow me to have Gitem as a field within Monster?

Comment: You can declare them in any order. The only requirement is that the second one gets the `and` keyword instead of `type`.

Comment: @DanielPeedah Yes, exactly as you said.